# How can replace the arguments -soundhw all in kvm command?

Tags: debian, qemu, kvm

Several years before,i run virtual machine this way:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-kvm
cd ~/
mkdir debian_qume
wget some_debian_version.iso  #it is a url
mv some_debian_version.iso  ~/debian_qume/
cd  debian_qume
qemu-img create -f qcow2 virtualdebian.img 30G
kvm -hda virtualdebian.img -cdrom some_debian_version.iso 
    -m 2048 -net nic -net user -soundhw all  &
```

It works fine,today (2013-07-10),the kvm command encounter some errors:

```
kvm -hda virtualdebian.img -cdrom some_debian_version.iso 
    -m 2048 -net nic -net user -soundhw all  &
```

The warning info:

```
kvm: warning: '-soundhw ac97' is deprecated, please use '-device AC97' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw gus' is deprecated, please use '-device gus' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw hda' is deprecated, please use '-device intel-hda -device hda-duplex' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw pcspk' is deprecated, please set a backend using '-machine pcspk-audiodev=<name>' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw es1370' is deprecated, please use '-device ES1370' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw sb16' is deprecated, please use '-device sb16' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw cs4231a' is deprecated, please use '-device cs4231a' instead
kvm: warning: '-soundhw adlib' is deprecated, please use '-device adlib' instead
```

How can replace the arguments `-soundhw all` in `kvm` command?
Os environment:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The audio devices in my pc:

```
lspci | grep -i audio
09:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
09:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
09:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Comment: `today (2013-10-07)` dear god what country uses year-day-month!! Oh, and welcome to 2023 :p - as to your question ... a) it's a *warning*, and b) it tells you what to do!

Comment: Like Jaromanda X said, those are not errors. It's a warning that the "-soundhw all" flag is deprecated and will likely be removed in some future version. I have found "-device intel-hda -device hda-duplex" works fine for Debian, but it's the only one I've tried. Maybe passing all of them will give you the same effect as "-soundhw all", but I've never tried it.